# Finding TeX Sources in C

Tags: tex-core, sourcecode

Why is it so hard to find TeX sources in C? I know the full source code is included in the `tex.web` and `pdftex.web` files, but isn't there any way to convert them to plain C code?

Comment: LuaTeX's source code is in C. See http://foundry.supelec.fr/gf/project/luatex/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fsource%2Ftexk%2Fweb2c%2Fluatexdir%2F

Comment: web2c will convert them to C

Comment: @Patrick Aren't they still in WEB-style format rather than more standard C?

Comment: @JosephWright I have to admit that I don't know.

Comment: @Patrick I'm basing my understanding on http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-3/tb96hoekwater-pascal.pdf, which indicates that some WEB is retained.

Comment: @JosephWright From that paper a quote that indicates like Taco and others have put a lot of time to make it like "standard C": "During conversion, quite a bit of effort went into making the source behave more
like a good C program should: most of the WEB macros with arguments have been converted into C #defines, most of the numerical WEB macros are now C enumerations,
and many of the WEB global variables are now function arguments or static variables."

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Apart from the machine-translation produced by web2c, there exist hand-translations into C code, e.g. cxtex, the LuaTeX sources, or someone's wonderful hobby project called [rsTeX](https://github.com/nadder/rstex).

Answer (score 23):

It's hard to find them because they don't exist. TeX is written in Pascal (one of the many flavors of it), but the source is interspersed with description of the code in the Web system devised by Knuth and others as part of a "literate programming" project.

The commented source is in `tex.web` (and `tex.ch`, a supplementary file where adaptations for specific operating systems are defined); one can get a `tex.tex` file by running

```
weave tex.web
```

and then compiling the file with `tex` or `pdftex`. The program code is obtained by running

```
tangle tex.web
```

that produces `tex.p`.

Modern distributions translate the Pascal code into C with a helper program, but I don't think that the C code is particularly readable. If you have available a TeX Live distribution, you can say

```
texdoc tex
```

which will open a PDF file with the commented Pascal code.

Comment: > It's hard to find them because they don't exist.  Well, they exist temporarily. Obviously they must exist, because they get fed to the C compiler. The conversion utility that the OP asked about (and which you mentioned in passing) is called web2c; it takes the tex.p output from tangle and converts it to tex.c

Comment: Ths C sources that temporarily exist are C sources, but not the C source for TeX.

Answer (score 3):

The C source code to Y&Y TeX, a once commercial product (Windows), has been released as free software. You can download it from http://code.google.com/p/yytex/