# Documentation of \mathop

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, learning, primitives

The Dirac delta distribution is ubiquitous in physics.  Since it is a special object I wanted to give it some extra spacing by using `\mathop`.  I know that single letters inside `\mathop` are centred around the math axis, whereas multiple letters are aligned with the baseline.  Here is a simple Plain TeX example:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{$\mathop{\delta} \mathop{\delta{}}$}
\noindent\rlap{\vrule width \wd0 height .1pt}\box0
\bye
```

[image]

However, I was not able to find this behaviour documented in the TeXbook.  Can someone suggest a reference for this?  I really would like to know the exact rules of when a `\mathop` is centred and when it is aligned at the baseline.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Appendix G rule 13 ends with the text

> Shift box~$x$ down by ${1\over2}\bigl(h(x)-d(x)\bigr)
>   -a$, where $a=\sigma_{22}$, so that the operator character is centered
>   vertically on the axis; this shifted box becomes the nucleus of the Op atom.

Comment: »If the nucleus is not a symbol [...] go to Rule 13a«.  Now what is a symbol?  Can you help me?

Comment: @HenriMenke in that context it means a single character so `\mathop{a}` is a symbol `\mathop{{}a}` isn't

Answer (score 18):

The description in `tex.web` is clearer. An *op_noad* is an atom built with `\mathop` or a mathchar of class 1. It follows that a *single character* is centered with respect to the math axis, but a “complex” nucleus won't. Note that `\mathop{{\delta}}` would not work, because the braces around a single character are always removed in math mode; more technically, a subformula consisting of a single character or of a single Acc atom is stripped off the braces and inserted as a normal atom.

[image]

Comment: I was wondering what `tex.web` is, so a search here brought up the [following answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37118/28751).